# Cancel a promise chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I chain a series of promises:

```
this.getData.then(this.getMoreData).then(this.getEvenMoreData);
```

At some point the user may decide to cancel the request and request something else.

How can I cancel the propagation of the chain?

Comment: What do you mean "the user"? This is a piece of code that's executed as quickly as possible, how would you add user intervention here?

Comment: The site is getting alot of data. If the user then requests other data, I want to halt getting the current set of data and outputting it.

Comment: So how would that play out? Is there a state object for this request that will indicate it was cancelled, like `var state = { running: true }` and then you can test `if (state.running) { return this.getMoreData() }` as necessary.

Comment: If you get your data via ajax you can cancel the request by [using the abort Method on the XMLHttpRequest object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery).

Comment: in case you use bluebird promises have a look at: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#cancellation . Basically the cancellation just works my throwing a custom object you can  then catch

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't use a single promise for this. Have you considered writing an async loop?

Comment: not clear what your asking. do you want to throw an exception or just cancel the propagation of the chain?

Comment: cancel the propagation of the chain please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd have to check for the state (of whether you should cancel or not) inside each chained method:

```
var userRequestedCancel = false;

this
   .getData()
   .then(function() {
     if(userRequestedCancel) {
      return Promise.reject('user cancelled');
     }

     return getMoreData();
   })
   .then(function() {
     if(userRequestedCancel) {
      return Promise.reject('user cancelled');
     }

     return getEvenMoreData();
   })
```

Or perhaps a slightly more elegant way (edited to pass context and arguments to `callback` methods)

```
var currentReq = false;
var userRequestedCancel = false;
var shouldContinue = function(cb,args) {
    if(userRequestedCancel) {
        return Promise.reject('user cancelled');
    }

    currentReq = cb.apply(this,args);
    return currentReq;
}

var onCancel = function() {
    userRequestedCancel = true;
    currentReq && currentReq.abort();
}

this
   .getData()
   .then(function() {
    return shouldContinue(getMoreData,arguments);
   })
   .then(function() {
     return shouldContinue(getEvenMoreData,arguments);
   })
```

If you need to cancel the current request as well, that is kind of trivial, set your current `ajax` request to be a global variable, and whatever event sets the `userRequestedCancel` flag to true, have that also cancel the `ajax` request (see edited code above)

Comment: Asuming getData() is some ajax request, the request should be aborted when the answer wasn't received yet.

Comment: @NickRussler - not really any more conceptually difficult. See edited code - keep a reference to the current ajax request and whenever you set `userRequestedCancel` to `true` - also cancel the last request.

Comment: yup, just mentioned it because op said "the site is getting **alot of data** [...]"

Comment: Thanks - what does the double && mean here? currentReq && currentReq.abort();

Comment: @panthro - it's a shorthand if - if the statement on the left (i.e. `currentReq`) is truth-y, then evaluate what comes after the `&&`  - It's the same as saying `if(currentReq) { currentReq.abort(); } ` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Just adding a note: good practice to let the Promise creator define how to reject a promise, and provide API for rejecting that API from other code as needed. Then if you use `async/await`, all `await` statements throw, going up the call stack. Usually you can leave any code in the stack untouched (unless you need to modify an existing try-catch block), and all code after the await statements are canceled!

Comment: Then, at the top of the stack (wherever you wish the error propagation to stop) add a try catch to silence the cancellation error. This is great at cancelling a big call stack that is awaiting on a network request. Just make sure that any code that needs to clean up will clean up (i.e. add a try-catch where needed, and remember to pass the error along by re-throwing it).

Answer (score 3):

In order to cancel a promise chain you need to throw an error. Just have a look at the code below

```
function CancelError() {
    this.message = 'Cancelled';
}


obj
    .then(function() {
        throw new CancelError();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        if (err instanceof CancelError) {
            // Promise got cancelled
        }
        throw err; // throw the other mistakes
    });
```

Comment: How would I throw an error from outside of the chain? If the user starts a new chain, I need to cancel the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Fun little challenge!

Without knowing exactly which task, request or process you're launching AND how the user can interrupt the said process, it's difficult to recommend any solution to "break" a `.then(...)` chain without doing some hack / trick that will trigger the `.catch(...)` rejection callback.

That being said, see if this example sheds some light at all.

Pay particular attention to the **makeInterruptablePromise** function and how it's used:

```js
var bar = $('.progress-bar');
var h3 = $("h3");
var isEscape;

function log(msg, replace) {
  h3[replace ? 'html' : 'append'](msg + "<br/>");
}

$(document).keydown(e => {
  switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 27: //ESCAPE
      return isEscape = true;
    case 32: //SPACE
      return runDemo();
  }
});

function makeInterruptablePromise(cbStatus) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    function loop() {
      switch(cbStatus()) {
        case 1: return resolve();
        case -1: return reject();
        default: requestAnimationFrame(loop);
      }
    }
    //Don't forget to start the loop!
    loop();
  })
}


function runDemo() {
  log("Wait for it... (ESC to interrupt, SPACE to replay)", true);
  
  isEscape = false;
  
  var timeToComplete = 2000;
  var timeStart = Date.now();
  
  function updateBar() {
    var timeDiff = Date.now() - timeStart;
    var timePercent = timeDiff / timeToComplete;
    TweenMax.set(bar, {scaleX: 1 - timePercent});
    return timePercent > 1;
  }
  
  makeInterruptablePromise(() => {
    if(isEscape) return -1;
    if(updateBar()) return 1;

    return 0;
  })
    .then(() => log("Inside *then* chain."))
    .catch(() => log("Skipped *then* chain!"))
}

runDemo(); //Run first time.
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #123456;
  color: #fff;
}

.progress-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #88f;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress-bar"></div>

<h3></h3>
```

What this essentially boils down to, is I'm passing a callback to `makeInterruptablePromise` to "monitor" for 3 possible statuses.

- If it's 1: It resolves (goes into your 'then')
- If it's -1: It rejects (skips to your 'catch')
- Otherwise, it just keeps looping by using the browser's `requestAnimationFrame(...)` method. 
  (essentially a `setTimeout(...)` calibrated to trigger per screen
  refreshes).

Now, to affect how these statuses changes over time, I demonstrated this by using `ESCAPE` as the interrupt status (-1) and a timer that runs for 2 seconds. Once complete, the timer returns status (1).

Not sure it can fit your need, but could be useful for anyone else trying to break Promises via some external / asynchronous factor.